# How to create a conditional EventHandler

Tags: front-end, eventhandler, user-interface

## Summary

Can we make something like the following work as an action for `EventHandler`?

```
"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`If[condition, action1, KernelExecute[action2]]
```

## Detailed question

Is there a way to create an `EventHandler` that does one of several things, based on some decision made by the front-end?

If we are allowed to use the kernel, we can simply use e.g.

```
"MouseClicked" :> If[condition, action1, action2]
```

for the event handler action. However, if e.g. `action1` can be performed entirely in the front-end, it would be nice if we didn't have to involve the kernel at all. If neither action needs the kernel, we can use

```
"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`If[condition, action1, action2]
```

for the action.

### Question

My question now is: Can we have a mixed case? Something like this, but working:

```
"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`If[condition, action1, KernelExecute[action2]]
```

### Example

As a concrete example, how can we make the following work?

```
DynamicModule[
 {mode = False, var1 = True, var2},
 {
  Checkbox@Dynamic@mode,
  EventHandler[Panel@"Click me", {
    "MouseClicked" :> FE`Evaluate@FEPrivate`If[mode,
       FEPrivate`Set[var1, FEPrivate`Not[var1]],
       var2 = RandomReal[]
       ]
    }],
  Checkbox@Dynamic@var1,
  Dynamic@var2
  }
 ]
```

The goal is to do something when the panel is clicked, with the action depending on the state of the first checkbox:

- If it is checked, toggle the state of the second checkbox. This should be done entirely in the front-end
- If it is unchecked, assign a new random value to `var2`. This clearly needs the kernel (it also needs access to the kernel, which is where my attempts have failed so far)

### Attempts

#### Direct approach

The closest I've gotten so far is with the following:

```
"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`FrontEndExecute[
   FEPrivate`If[condition, action1, EvaluatePacket[action2]]
]
```

This manages to call the kernel only when necessary, but has several problems:

- As far as I can tell, this uses the front-ends service kernel, and not the evaluator of the notebook.
- It is very tricky to get variables to work with this: The front-end doesn't wrap the kernel call in the usual `` FE`ExecuteInDynamicModule ``, which means that a lot of trickery is needed to get access to the variables of the `DynamicModule` (if it is possible at all, since the kernel called doesn't have `` FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$… `` set)
- The front-end blindly inserts values for the variables. This can be stopped with `ReleaseHold@Hold@…`, but then the previous point still causes issues

#### Work-around

The following workaround seems to work, but is very hacky and might become very convoluted:

```
DynamicModule[
 {mode = False, var1 = True, var2, trigger = False},
 {
  Checkbox@Dynamic@mode,
  EventHandler[Panel@"Click me", {
    "MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`If[mode,
      FEPrivate`Set[var1, FEPrivate`Not[var1]],
      FEPrivate`Set[trigger, FEPrivate`Not[trigger]]]
    }],
  Checkbox@Dynamic@var1,
  Dynamic@var2,
  Dynamic[trigger; var2 = RandomReal[]; "", TrackedSymbols :> {trigger}]
  }
 ]
```

The idea is to cause some `Dynamic` to update when we need to call the kernel. Here, we change `trigger` in the front-end, which causes the last `Dynamic` expression to update once, assigning a new value to `var2`.

Comment: The only FE symbol (i.e. `FEPrivate`, `FrontEnd`, `FE`, etc...) that should be present in your `EventHandler` function is ``FEPrivate`Set``.

Comment: @ihojnicki Interesting, thanks! Could you elaborate a bit on why this works? I was always under the impression that if the ``FEPrivate`*`` variant exists, then it is equivalent to the normal one, just FE-only, while the `System` variant might or might not be understood by the FE. But here it seems that the two `If` "variants" are not equivalent. Furthermore, trying `Which` and ``FEPrivate`Which`` shows the opposite behaviour: Only the `FEPrivate` version works, the `System` one does not (since the FE just send the ``FEPrivate`Set`` to the kernel, which doesn't understand what to do with that).

Comment: The `FEPrivate` symbols are partial implementations of the `System` variant.  The FE understands `If` because it has a version that complies with the documented behaviors of ``System`If``.  The same cannot be said about `Which`.  That is also why they are undocumented, at some point they will inevitably be deprecated and removed.

Comment: And one point about the `EventHandler` function.  The evaluator submits the entire function to the kernel when it encounters a symbol in the expression that it is unwilling to evaluate.

Comment: @ihojnicki Thanks for the clarifications! There is one thing that still confuses me a bit: Consider the event-handler you suggested: ``If[mode, FEPrivate`Set[var1, FEPrivate`Not[var1]], var2 = RandomReal[]]``. In this case, the FE only sends the `var2 = …` to the kernel if needed, meaning it evaluated the condition on its own, and ignores the unknown symbols when `mode` is `True`, since they are all in the else-clause. With `If[mode, var1 = ! var1, var2 = RandomReal[]]` however, it always sends the entire thing to the kernel, meaning it doesn't evaluate the condition, event though it could.

Comment: So let me see if I understood you correctly: For ``FEPrivate`If``, it seems it is not so clever - as soon as it sees any unknown symbol, it sends the entire thing to the kernel. For ``FEPrivate`Which``, it is the other way around: It doesn't know ``System`Which``, so it will send the entire expression in all cases. The ``FEPrivate`Which`` variant on the other hand is clever enough, and can send only the relevant parts to the kernel. Is this what you meant?

Comment: And one last question: Which symbols are you referring to when you say "undocumented and will be deprecated"? The FEs implementations of `System` symbols, or the `FEPrivate` symbols (which are documented in some way)

Comment: You should try it in Linksnooper.  You will see the FE sends the entire expression to the kernel when `RandomReal` needs to be called.  ``TimeConstrained[If[FE`mode$$26, FEPrivate`Set[FE`var1$$26, Not[FE`var1$$26]], Set[FE`var2$$26, RandomReal[]]]``

Comment: The `FEPrivate` symbols.  They come with no future guarantees.

Comment: @ihojnicki Thanks once again! I could have sworn it didn't send the whole expression when I checked with LinkSnooper, but I must have looked at the wrong part of that line...